# how to add last two month column data dynamically based on item number in power bi

Tags: dax

for eg in nov 23 for product 3245 having order of 50,

in dec 23 for product 3245 having order of 45

output:

in jan 24 for product 3245 order should be 50 + 40=90 (nov23 product 3245 order + dec 23 product 3245 order).

It has to go dynamically for feb 24, jan24+dec 23.
sample data

| Product | location | monthyear | order | MonthSeq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3245 | abc | Nov-23 | 34 | 23 |
| 3245 | abc | Oct-23 | 56 | 22 |
| 5255 | xyz | Nov-23 | 45 | 23 |
| 5255 | xyz | Oct-23 | 96 | 22 |

how to achieve this in power bi

Comment: Where is the product A in your dataset? spend time and fix the question and use more words to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to capture the month that is selected, then remove context filters, to look at the other rows. Something like:

```
My Measure = 
  var thisMonth = MAX('YourTable'[MonthSeq])
  return
    CALCULATE(
      SUM('YourTable'[order]),
      ALLEXCEPT('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Product]),
      'YourTable'[MonthSeq] >= thisMonth - 2 && 'YourTable'[MonthSeq] < thisMonth
    )
```

Comment: i am using direct query mode, getting error. The resultset of a query to external data source has exceeded the maximum allowed size of '1000000'. can we have product and location. to sum the order.

Comment: Do you have a proper date column?

Comment: no date table or column, having monthyear and monthseq